# How do I prevent my output from being Nan?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, nan

I am trying to make a budgeting app that will alert the user the remainder after subtracting income by expenses, my alert keeps saying Nan. I am using for loops to sum up my income and expense inputs from the user. I have included my code.

Thanks!

```
function Maincalc(){
  var incomeVal = document.getElementsByClassName("income");
  var expenseVal = document.getElementsByClassName("expenses");
  var tot = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < incomeVal.length; i++){
      if(parseInt(incomeVal[i].value))
          var incomeTot = tot + parseInt(incomeVal[i].value);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < expenseVal.length; i++){
      if(parseInt(expenseVal[i].value))
          var expenseTot = tot + parseInt(expenseVal[i].value);
}
var x = incomeTot - expenseTot;
alert(x);
}

var btn = document.getElementById("submit");

btn.addEventListener("click", Maincalc);
```

Comment: 1: don't use `alert`, it is ancient and effectively useless. Use the console API (`console.log` etc) or use a real modal. 2: what's an example of this going wrong? (e.g. what values are involved when things "break"?)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I was thinking that maybe the for loop that is summing the input values is not working properly.

Comment: What is `value` in `incomeVal[i].value`? If you're trying to get the inner text inside an html element, it should be `incomeVal[i].textContent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set a variable to parseInt(...) and check to make sure that it is a number using `if(!isNaN(val)`.  See my example below.

Side note, you had some variables declared inside the for blocks which didn't make a lot of sense.

```js
function Maincalc() {
  var incomeVal = document.getElementsByClassName("income");
  var expenseVal = document.getElementsByClassName("expenses");
  var incomeTot = 0;
  var expenseTot = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < incomeVal.length; i++) {
    let val = parseInt(incomeVal[i].value);
    if (!isNaN(val))
      incomeTot += val;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < expenseVal.length; i++) {
    let val = parseInt(expenseVal[i].value)
    if (!isNaN(val))
      expenseTot += val;
  }
  var x = incomeTot - expenseTot;
  alert(x);
}

Maincalc();
```

```html
<input class="income" value="12" />
<input class="income" value="12" />
<input class="income" value="a" />

<input class="expenses" value="5"/>
<input class="expenses" value="5"/>
<input class="expenses" value="b"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! This made my code finally work! parseInt makes incomeVal & and expense val, intergers or does it analyse the string for intergers? I am still learn JS, so pardon if my questions are odd lol.

Comment: It will attempt to parse them to an int and if it fails it returns isNaN

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your HTML or a functioning example is hard to tell, but I would change a couple of things.

As other commenters said, use `console.log` to see the partial execution of your code and see where the number is a Nan.

I would also change this line, where the error is probably occuring:

```
     if(parseInt(expenseVal[i].value))
```

to:

```
  if (!isNaN(expenseVal[i].value)) {
```

To verify that the number is valid and is a number; also, when using parseInt pass the second argument to ensure the numbers are parsed valid and about bugs, like this `parseInt(incomeVal[i].value, 10)`. Unrelated too, but a map or reduce function would be better for this case too.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the DOM nodes returned by `document.getElementsByClassName("income")` and `document.getElementsByClassName("expenses")` contain a numeric value.

What kind of DOM nodes do `income` and `expenses` classes represent? Please share the HTML snippet